# How to implement infrequent method/interface in list of classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, java-7

Let's say I have a class called **Element** which is a superclass for all kinds of elements; **Wall**, **Door**, **Pickup**, **Table**, etc. Now suppose, some of these subclasses can be interacted with by an instance of **Player** via a *use()* method, but others can not. Only 1-5% of all the elements will be usable. How would I implement this in an object-orientated fashion?

I have considered the following options:

- Element can contain an overridable *use()* method, which can be overriden by each subclass. This is easy to implement but requires the player to check the *use()* method from a lot of objects when interacting with the world.
- Some subclasses can implement an **Usable** interface, which defines the *use()* method. This requires the program to keep track of at least two lists, one for **Element**'s and one for **Usable**'s.
- Use one list for **Elements** and use the *instanceof* operator to check for usability. Really?

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: My first reaction was to have the subclasses implement a `Usable` interface, as you mentioned.  What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the usability depends on the class, and not on the instance of the object, you could simply provide these two methods in the base class:

```
public boolean isUsable() {
    return false;
}

public void use() {
    if (isUsable()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("subclass must override use() if it's usable");
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not usable I told you");
}
```

The subclasses that want to be usable now simply need to override these two methods.

If the usability depends on the instance, then you can use a flag:

```
private final boolean usable;

protected Element(boolean usable) {
    this.usable = usable;
}

public final boolean isUsable() {
    return usable;
}

public final void use() {
    if (!isUsable()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not usable I told you");
    }
    doUse();
}

protected void doUse() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("subclass that can be usable must override doUse");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot to mention explicitly that the usability depends on the class, and not on class objects. For your (first) solution; if I have a large arraylist of world elements, of whcih only 1% is usable, wouldn't this create a large overhead when looping through the element list searching for the best usable candidate?

Comment: For a good answer, you'll have to describe your problem. How many elements do you have. What is the algorithm supposed to do? What is a candidate and how do you look for the best one? Edit your question.

Comment: Didn't I describe the problem fairly well? The amount of instances of (subclasses of) elements can be anywhere between 50-1000, depending on the size of the world. Only 5-30 objects will be instances of a usable subclass. At a certain moment in time, when a certain *use* action is required, an object within the player's reach is a candidate, and the best candidate will be the one closest to the player. Thanks for your time to answer my questions!

Comment: Iterating over 1000 elements is very fast. If it's not fast enough, then you can maintain an additional collection of usable objects.